# How to use missing parameter of XGBRegressor of scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am working on a dataset which contains missing values in certain columns. I am trying to use XGBRegressor of Scikit-Learn wrapper interface for XGBoost. There it provides a parameter called 'missing' in which you can enter float values or otherwise it takes NaN of python as default. So i need help like how can i use this parameter to fill missing values of the columns in my dataset. It will be helpful if one can provide me a simple example as well.

Comment: When you supply some float value as `missing`, then if that specific value is present in your data, it is treated as missing value. For example if you specify missing = 0.1, then wherever 0.1 is present, it will be treated as a missing value. [Look here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/21) for more details on handling of missing values

Comment: So is there a way to retrieve the modified dataset which has been modified by xgboost

Comment: I dont think it modifies the dataset. Just decides the direction of split for fitting when it encounters a missing value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The missing value parameter works as whatever value you provide for 'missing' parameter it treats it as missing value. For example if you provide 0.5 as missing value, then wherever it finds 0.5 in your data it treats it as missing value. Default is NaN. So what XGBoost does is based on the data it defines one of the path as default path. For example based on one parameter say it can go in two directions either left or right, so one of that will be made default based on the data. So whenever one of the missing value comes as input for a parameter, say you defined 0.5 as missing, then whenever 0.5 comes in the data it takes the default path. Initially I thought it imputes the missing value but it does not. It just defines one of the path as default and whenever any missing value come it takes that default path. This is defined in the paper [XGBoost: A Scalable Tree Boosting System](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.02754)

Answer (score 1):

its my understanding you got it mixed up.
The missing parameter only replaces a certain value (or list of values) for missing (aka NaN) - the default is "np.nan"

if you want to replace the actual missing values for some different value, lets say "X" you gotta do it on your data before applying the model.

if you got a dataframe "df" you can:

```
df.fillna(X)
```

if you got a np.array "array" you can:

```
np.nan_to_num(array)
```

but the above will replace the np.nan with zeros.

hope that helps,

Comment: i want to know what it actually does. does it simply replaces the missing value with some default value like zero or it tries to predict what should be the value in place of that missing value.

Comment: my understanding of it is that it simply replaces the value.